# Missing glibtoolize

Tags: xcode, homebrew

One package I want to install (lua-posix) needs glibtoolize, where do I get that? I installed XCode and that Development Console Tools stuff, brew doctor is happy, and according to the them, glibtoolize should somewhere come from Apple.

What do I need to install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, and i installed *libtool* via *brew*

```
brew install libtool
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't know how I could miss this simple solution!